# Enum in C is not throwing an error on invalid input

Tags: c, enums

I am using gcc and I compiled this code and it should have thrown an error but it ran successfully.

```
enum DIRECTION {EAST,WEST,NORTH,SOUTH};

int main(void) {
    enum DIRECTION currentDirection = 10;
    printf("%d\n",currentDirection);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : 
10

Comment: why do you think it should throw error?

Comment: as per I know , enums do not allow any other values.

Comment: C is not quite as strongly typed as you'd wish it to be...

Comment: Your enum is just an "int". Hence, you can assign an out-of-range number

Comment: I tried to compile same code with g++ and it threw this error
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘DIRECTION’

Comment: That's true in `C++` when you define `enum` with `class` keyword.

Comment: If enums do not serve the very purpose for which they are used then what is the meaning of having them in C language.
for example I could have written same code with 
#define North 0 \n
#define South 1 \n 
#define East 2 \n
#define West 3 \n
int currentDirection;
but here I can set currentDirection to whatever I want but with enums I can have values between 0 and 3 only.

Comment: The purpose is to not only name values, but also their intended purpose. They are "the same thing". Also, I think you'd get a warning if you compile with `-pedantic -Wall`.

Comment: Nope , I didn't get any warning.

Comment: so @StoryTeller you mean to say that 
I can use EAST as trivial constant that's it.

Comment: @StoryTeller `gcc` will not warn but `clang` will see details in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enums type is defined in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.2.2` *Enumeration specifiers* as:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,<sup>110)</sup> [...]

where footnote `110` says:

> An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen.

the standard does not say you are not allowed to specify a value outside of those specified in the declaration of the enum although in section `Annex I` *Common warnings* it does suggest such a warning but it is not required:

> A value is given to an object of an enumerated type other than by assignment of an
>   enumeration constant that is a member of that type, or an enumeration object that has
>   the same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumerated type (6.7.2.2).

`gcc` will not produce a warning although `clang` with the `-Wassign-enum` flag or `-Weverything` flag will and it would look similar to this:

> warning: integer constant not in range of enumerated type 'enum DIRECTION' [-Wassign-enum]

and you can use `-Werror` to make it an error.

Keith makes two interesting observations:

- Using `-Werror` would make `clang` non-conforming since the code is valid *C*.
- `enum DIRECTION currentDirection = 128;` has implementation defined behavior since the type could well be *char*.

Comment: Note that using `-Werror` makes gcc non-conforming. The code in the question is strictly conforming (once you add the required `#include <stdio.h>`), and a conforming compiler may not reject it (unless it violates some bizarre capacity restriction).

Comment: Another interesting tidbit: `enum DIRECTION currentDirection = 10;` is valid, but `enum DIRECTION currentDirection = 128;` has implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson interesting, I see what your saying.

Answer (score 3):

In C an enum constant is the equivalent of an int. You can use them interchangeably.

Comment: An `enum` type is a distinct type, compatible with some implementation-defined integer type (not necessarily `int`). Enumeration constants, on the other hand, are of type `int`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The code in the question uses an `int` constant to initialize an `enum DIRECTION` object. The fact that the enum constants `EAST` et all are of type `int` is not immediately relevant, since the code doesn't use any of the enumerators. What's relevant is that an `enum` type is effectively an implementation-defined integer type, and initializing such an object with an `int` constant involves an implicit conversion.

Comment: It can be inferred from other language rules that the maximum value of the integer type with which `enum DIRECTION` is compatible is wide enough to represent the value `10`.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` (enumeration) is a type that can hold a set of integer values specified by the user. It's a way of creating symbolic names for a small list of related values. Their purpose is to make programs clearer and more readable.

The values of an `enum` type are called enumerators. The enumerators are in the same scope as the `enum` and their values implicitly convert to integers.

A macro is meant for the preprocessor, and the compiled code has no idea about the macros you create. They have been already replaced by the preprocessor before the code hits the compiler. An enum is a compile time entity, and the compiled code retains full information about the symbol, which is available in the debugger (and other tools).

Also it's convenient to add a new symbolic name later and let the values reorder themselves. However `enum`s in `C` are not strongly typed and are compatible with signed integers. So you can assign any value to an `enum` type variable.

```
// APPLE == 0, PEARS == 1, ...

enum fruits {APPLE, PEARS, BANANA};

// APPLE == 0, MANGO == 1, PEARS == 2, ...

enum fruits {APPLE, MANGO, PEARS, BANANA};
enum color {APPLE, PEACH};

enum color my_color = MANGO;  // not strongly typed
enum fruits my_fruit = 7; // int -> enum fruits conversion
```

However `enum` in `C++` is strongly typed.

```
enum class Traffic_light {red, yellow, green};
enum class Warning {green, yellow, orange, red};

Warning w = 1; // error. no int -> Warning implicit conversion
Traffic_light t = Warning::red; // type error. Warning::red is a different type
```